# Undefined method 'username' in comments even though users are referenced

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried setting up a comment system on my application. I have made a migration for the comments so all the comments have a user_id and post_id referenced with them. I have added `has_many :comments, through: :posts` in my user model. I have also added `has_many :comments` in my posts controller. In my comments controller I have also added `belongs_to :post` and the same for `belongs_to :user`. The problem occurs though when I try to call anything from the user model through an html.erb. When I make a comment through the console everything goes through fine and I can see what user made the comment, but when I try to even display any comments everything go sideways. Here is the part which is causing the error:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <h3><%= comment.user.username %></h3>
  <h4><%= comment.body %></h4>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It throws me an error in the username part giving me: `` undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass ``. Also, this occurs one every post even if that post doesn't have any comments. The body does work though.

Comment: How are you defining user?

Comment: This is one of the "magic" things that makes Rails famous. Take your time. I recommend an early RailsCasts episode, if they are sill accessible. Viva!

Comment: the error tells you that `comment.user` is nil. So probably the database does not contain what you expect. In the rails console, check each instance of `Comment` and make sure there is a valid `user_id` value. Valid meaning that it's an integer and that there is a `User` model with that integer as its id.

Comment: The thing is that there are no rows of any comments in the database. I just deleted everything inside the comment model and the comment.user still shows as nil.

Comment: Can I see your controller?

Comment: "In my comments controller I have also added belongs_to :post and the same for belongs_to :user". Say what? Associations are defined in your models - not controllers. Please add the relevant models to the question. One part of the issue here is also very likely that you have defined the `comments.user_id` column as nullable which let bad data get in in the first place.

Comment: You have your answer, or maybe you should be asking a different question?

Comment: No, my bad I meant to say that it was in my model (not my controller). I think the issue might be because I was creating comments the wrong way but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass
```

This is caused by the fact that username is not a property of nil
You need to account for the fact that for some of your records, probably legacy data before you wrote the code to handle the associations, there is no user associated with a comment.

Change your view code to check for nil

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <h3><%= comment.user.username unless comment.user.blank? || comment.user.username.blank?%></h3>
  <h4><%= comment.body %></h4>
  </div> <%# why a random closing div here, remove it or move it to a more appropriate location to match an opening div%>
<% end %>
```

Or perhaps a little nicer

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <h3>
     <%if comment.user.blank?%>
        No user associated with this comment
     <%= else comment.user.username.blank?%>
  </h3>
  <h4><%= comment.body %></h4>
  </div> <%# why a random closing div here, remove it or move it to a more appropriate location to match an opening div%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Here's the thing, I cleared all of my records (for comment model) and even checked in the database and didn't see any tables rows, but it still gave me an error telling me it was nil.

Comment: @guest0197 Well, here is the other thing then. Your error is not lying to you so you clearly DO have a comment with no user attached or a user with no username. So when you have amended your code in your view appropriately you will be able to see exactly which comment is causing you the trouble. Feel free to come back once you have fixed your view

Comment: @jamesc I think you might solve this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886524/gem-devise-how-to-add-comment-created-user-email

Answer (score -1):

Root, because when you created comment, you did not set `comment.user` (example `comment.user = current_user`) before save.
Check your code in CommentsController -> method `create`