# gem devise how to add comment created user email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, authentication, devise, comments

I am using gem devise for creating users profile
Each user can create a comment. I need to add the user name beside each comment something like this `<%= @comment.user.name %>`

in user.rb

```
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

in comment.rb

```
  belongs_to :users
```

in comment controller

```
before_action :find_comment ,only:[:show,:update,:edit,:destroy]

   def new
    @user =User.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @user.comments.build
  end

  def create
    @user =User.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to doctor_path(:id => @user.id)
    end
  end

private

  def find_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
  end
```

user controller

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

user show.html.erb

```
<% for item in @user.comments %>
  <% if item.text.present? %>
    <%= item.text %><br>        
    <%= @comment.user.name %>
    <br><hr>
  <% end %>
```

I got this error

```
undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: I am not clear on what your question is. What do you want to do with email?

Comment: @jamesc I want to add the user name for the comment. for example I am writing a comment and my name is nourza. My name will display behind the comment

Comment: You will need to use comment.user.name somewhere but you haven't provided enough info to give an a clear answer

Comment: @jamesc What info do you need?

Comment: <%= @comment.user.name %> I got this error undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question and show what you've tried and show your error. I am confused as your question is about email.

Comment: @jamesc I edit my question

Comment: That is still a very unclear question. To get clear answers you MUST be exact in what you are asking for. I have given you an answer that I hope helps

Comment: I added the models above

Comment: That belongs_to is wrong. The problem you are having is the way you have this setup. I'll see if I can come up with a solution for you

Comment: @jamesc I would be appreciate it

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the other way around, in your `show` method:

`@comments = Comment.all`

in your `show` view:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.text %>
  <%= comment.user.name %>
<% end %>
```

Since your question is not really clear I'll specifiy that if you want to show just the comments posted by the user:

```
def show
  user_id = User.find(params[:id]).id
  @comments = Comment.where(user_id: user_id)
end
```

Comment: Yes I want to show just the comments posted by the user. how should I add in the show view?

Comment: The same way I did in the first example when `@comments = Comment.all`, since you're just changing the variable

Comment: When I add this @comments = Comment.all to the user controller show I got this error undefined method `user' for #<Comment:0x007fdee6f23ab0>
Did you mean?  users

Comment: Then make sure everything is ok with your `has_many` relationship (and that you have run migrations of course): https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Comment: And try running stuff your console to test things like `User.first.comments` etc.. and see what the output is

Comment: User.third.comments
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
  Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 3]]
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | text                                                  | user_id | created_at              | updated_at              |

Comment: I want to have the devise gem user name or the email to show under the comment.

Comment: Everything looks fine for me. Make sure every comment has a user and it should work.

Comment: Do you think it something should I add in the routes? resources :comments

Comment: I don't think that should change anything, I tried offering some solutions but in the end you're the one with the code! Experiment with what I and the others gave you and if you have other ideas then go for it and see if it solves your problem, and read the docs ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just some quick rules to start with

1. A user has many comments, this will be the relationship between the user and a comment that the user has made.
   You already have this
2. A user has many profile comments, this is the relationship between a user and the comments that have been left for that user on their profile

Now you have that distinction things start to be come clearer.

Start by creating a single xref table to act as the go between users and comments that have been left for a profile and call it `profile_comments`
this `profile_comments` table needs a `user_id` and a `comment_id` of type integer to store the primary keys from user and comments tables, where the `user_id` is the id of the user that is having a comment left about them on their profile

You can now setup a `profile_comment` model that with the following relationships

```
belongs_to comment
belongs_to user
```

So now you need to change your user model relationships to the following

user.rb

```
  has_many :comments
  has_many :profile_comments, dependent: :destroy
```

comment.rb

```
  belongs_to :user #not users as you have defined in your question
  has_many :profile_comments, dependent: :destroy
```

and the new `profile_comment.rb` model needs the two `belongs_to` clauses for comment and user

profile_comment.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :comment
```

Now when you create a comment you need to assign to to the user, and also to the profile_comment

So now your comments controller needs to setup these relationships so instead of

```
before_action :find_comment ,only:[:show,:update,:edit,:destroy]

   def new
    @user =User.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @user.comments.build
  end

  def create
    @user =User.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to doctor_path(:id => @user.id)
    end
  end
```

You need something like this

```
  def create
    @user =User.find(params[:id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @profile_comment = ProfileComment.new
    @user.profile_comment < @profile_comment
    @comment.profile_comment < @profile_comment
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to doctor_path(:id => @user.id)
    end
  end
```

Your update action will need to also change accordingly

Now in your view instead of

```
<% for item in @user.comments %>
  <% if item.text.present? %>
    <%= item.text %><br>        
    <%= @comment.user.name %>
    <br><hr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You want this, it's a little complex because you need to get from the profile comment to the comment then to the user that created the comment

```
<% @user.profile_comments.each do | profile_comment |%>
  <%comment = profile_comment.comment%>
  <% if comment.text.present? %>
    <%= comment.text %><br>
    <%if comment.user.blank?%>
      No user assigned to this comment
    <%else%>
      <%= comment.user.name #or email or whatever%>
    <%end%>
    <br><hr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Although text is a reserved word and is an actual column type so you might want to change the column name text to something else

Any questions on this feel free to get back to me but I won't be around for the next 24 hours. Hope it's clear and helps you understand what has gone wrong with your initial setup

In the controller and the view I have assumed that the `current_user` is the person making the comment and `@user` is the person that is being commented on. Just switch that round if I have that wrong

Comment: No I want each comment to show just the comments posted by the user. for example x user posted comment to show x user name. y user posted comment to show y name.

Comment: Any user can comment in any profile. I want each user name to show behind the comment. like these comments.

Comment: @nourza Still confused, so when viewing a profile you want to see comments on that profile and the name of the user that made the comment? That is what I have given you

Comment: yes this is what i want but the result is something else. The result gives all the comments the same user name of the profile. for example profile x have comments under x name, not comments under the posted name

Comment: @nourza, now it is becoming a little clearer. Can you post your models please particularly the relationships, I may need more but that should do for the minute

Comment: Thank you! I got this error PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column profile_comments.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...profile_comments".* FROM "profile_comments" WHERE "profile_c...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "profile_comments".* FROM "profile_comments" WHERE "profile_comments"."user_id" = $1

Comment: @nourza, you question intimates you laready have that relationship setup but clearly uou havern't so you need a user_id on the profile comments table

Comment: @norza, just go through and check you have all the foreign keys setup properly

Comment: I got this error can't write unknown attribute `user_id`

Comment: Cudos for trying but this really just makes more of a mess when the problem could be solved by just adding to foreign key columns to the comments table and two separate associations. The core of the issue here is really just a very common scenario where you have two associations pointing to the same table.