# can't write unknown attribute `user_id`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, devise, migration

I am using gem devise for creating user profiles. Every user can create comments in any profile I want to add each user name under the comment he wrote.

A user has many comments

A user has many profile comments, this is the relationship between a user and the comments This is the error that I got when I create a comment

```
can't write unknown attribute `user_id`
```

Here is what I did

```
class CreateProfileComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :profile_comments do |t|
    
          t.timestamps null: false
        end
      end
    end

class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :text
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

in user.rb model

```
  has_many :comments
  has_many :profile_comments, dependent: :destroy
```

in comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user #not users as you have defined in your question
  has_many :profile_comments
end
```

in profile comment.rb

```
class ProfileComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :user
end
```

in comment controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_comment ,only:[:show,:update,:edit,:destroy]

   def new
    @user =User.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @user.comments.build
  end

  def index

  end

  def create
    @user =User.find(params[:id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @profile_comment = ProfileComment.new
    @user.profile_comments < @profile_comment
    @comment.profile_comment < @profile_comment
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to doctor_path(:id => @user.id)
    end
  end 

  def edit
  end

  def update

    if @comment.update(comment_params)
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "user Information updated successfully"
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Couldn't update!"
      render :edit
    end
  end
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to doctors_path, notice: "comment deleted Successfully"
  end 

private

  def find_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
  end
end
```

in user profile view

```
      <% @user.profile_comments.each do | profile_comment |%>
  <%comment = profile_comment.comment%>
  <% if comment.text.present? %>
    <%= comment.text %><br>
    <%if comment.user.blank?%>
      No user assigned to this comment
    <%else%>
      <%= comment.user.name #or email or whatever%>
    <%end%>
    <br><hr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't get where you got the idea for the `ProfileComment` model/table in the first place. What is supposed to accomplish and why do you think you need it?

Comment: Start by creating a single xref table to act as the go between users and comments that have been left for a profile and call it profile_comments this profile_comments table needs a user_id and a comment_id of type integer to store the primary keys from user and comments tables, where the user_id is the id of the user that is having a comment left about them on their profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing what you actually want is just to create two assocations pointing to the same table:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :text
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :author, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Here `user_id` references the target user of the comment and  `author_id` references the user writing the comment. Both reference `users.id`.

Then create two `belongs_to` associations in your comment model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :author, 
    class_name: 'User', 
    inverse_of: :authored_comments
end
```

And two `has_many` associations in your User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # comments about this user
  has_many :comments 
  # comments written by this user 
  has_many :authored_comments, 
    class_name: 'Comment',
    foreign_key: :author_id,
    inverse_of: :author
end
```

I have no idea why you would want to mix in another table as both relations are one to many.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:new, :create]
  
  # ...

  def new
    @comment = @user.comments.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = @user.comments.new(comment_params) do |c|
      c.author = current_user
    end
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to doctor_path(id: @user.id)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end 

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # ...
end
```

If you then want to display comments you would do:

```
<% @user.comments.each do |comment| %>
<div class="comment">
  <div class="body">
    <%= comment.body %>
  </div>
  <p class="author"><%= comment.author.email %></p>
</div>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. Please don' change the names. so I have here profile_comments. to make it easier check this answer because I used it in my codes https://stackoverflow.com/a/62923853/6392696

Comment: Please check the link that I attached. It will make it easier

Comment: That answer is not good at all.  I'm trying to show you that you're making it way more complex then its supposed to be.

Comment: This is a really common scenario where you need two assocations that happen to point to the same table and you didn't explain what it is you are trying to do very well and the people answering the question didn't understand it either.

Comment: Oh ok sorry for that. rails g migration add_column_to_comment author:references then I got this error when i do rake db:migrate PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "authors" does not exist

Comment: You need to use `add_reference :comments, :author, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }` in your migration.

Comment: I still got this PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "authors" does not exist

Comment: You didn't save the file or something else. I tried running the exact same migration and it works just fine.

Comment: rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "authors" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_f44b1e3c8a"
FOREIGN KEY ("author_id")
  REFERENCES "authors" ("id")

Comment: You're still messing up the migration. https://gist.github.com/maxcal/ffc8424e6939a2150ebbb046377aab09

Comment: I still got this error rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "authors" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_f44b1e3c8a"
FOREIGN KEY ("author_id")
  REFERENCES "authors" ("id")

Comment: Should I create author model?

Comment: I fix it to t.references :author